# What's the purpose of using bind() when SOCK_DGRAM is used?

Tags: c, sockets, tftp

Here is a piece of code snippet from tftp

```c
void initsock(int af) {
    struct sockaddr_storage s_in;

    if (f >= 0)
        close(f);

    f = socket(af, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (f < 0) {
        perror("tftp: socket");
        exit(3);
    }
    printf("protocol family: %d\n", af);

    memset(&s_in, 0, sizeof(s_in));
    s_in.ss_family = af;
    if (bind(f, (struct sockaddr *)&s_in, sizeof (s_in)) < 0) {
        perror("tftp: bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    char ip_str[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = {0};

    inet_ntop(s_in.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&s_in), ip_str, sizeof ip_str);
    printf("ip address: %s\t port: %d\n", ip_str, get_in_port((struct sockaddr *)&s_in));
}
```

My question is that why bind() is called here? What's the purpose? The second argument seems empty except for ss_family field, no ip address nor port number.

p.s. Source code from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/tftp

Comment: What implementation of TFTP is this snippet from? Can you post a link to the repository?

Comment: Looks like it's used to bind to either IPv4 or IPv6 using the "ANY` address and an ephemeral port. So basically it's to select the IP version to use.

Answer (score 0):

`bind()` in this example uses INADDR_ANY as an address what means that
it binds to all available interfaces and port 0 that `man 2 bind`
refers to as an *ephemeral port* what means that it lets operating
system choose free port to use. You can add the following snippet at the end of this function and  use `getsockname()` to get
the number port number chosen by OS:

```
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(sa);

    if (getsockname(f, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, &addrlen) == -1) {
      perror("getsockname()");
    }

    printf("Local IP address is: %s\n", inet_ntoa(sa.sin_addr));
    printf("Local port is: %d\n", (int) ntohs(sa.sin_port));
```

Comment: Thanks. The ephemeral port appears in ERRORS section, which is overlooked when I read. Now I know the functionality of bind() here, but still the purpose is unclear. I mean the interface and port number can be chosen when calling sendto(). So why bother here. The port number is not used by the client since I search and find no getsockname result if that is a common way to get the port number.

Comment: I downloaded http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/netkit-tftp/netkit-tftp_0.17.orig.tar.gz but there is no function called `initsock()`. So let me ask again - where does this snippet in your question come from?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: Apparently comes from ubuntu patches applied to the source, http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/netkit-tftp/netkit-tftp_0.17-18ubuntu3.diff.gz

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk As Hasturkun remarked, it's from the patche added to orig by ubuntu. Actually, I didn't even notice that, since I downloaded using apt-get source. Forgive me for my carelessness. After applying the patch, it's located in tftp/main.c

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk "*You can ... use `getsockname()` to get the number port number chosen by OS*" - which is likely what the calls to `get_in_addr()` and `get_in_port()` are actually doing internally, prior to the `printf()` after `bind()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: possibly but I couldn't find a definition of `get_in_port()` anywhere in the linked tarball.

Comment: `get_in_addr()` and `get_in_port()` are both added by myself as helper functions to inspect the code. They cannot achieve the same functionality as `getsockname()` does, since they merely extract information from `struct sockaddr`. For example, `return ntohs((struct sockaddr_in*)sa->sin_port);`